# Android Studio: How can i change image of ImageView from other layout programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml

My ImageView is located in mylist.xml (not in mainActivity.xml) and I want the image to be change in MainActivity.java...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/listahan"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/contimage"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/Itemname"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code in MainActivity.java, I am using bitmap to get a photo from contacts and display it to ImageView.

```
        int thumbnailId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
        String contactID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        Bitmap bMap = loadContactPhoto2(getContentResolver(), new Long(contactID), new Long(thumbnailId));
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(), R.layout.mylist, R.id.Itemname, ns);
                getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Paste your code, where you have access to mylist.xml

Comment: I suppose in MainActivity you have a listview and adapter, haven't you?

Comment: I see you have. You should use custom adapter https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html